# Best way to give slim the contente of my submited form in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, forms, slim

I'm trying to send to my Slim API the data inside my form.

My form is:

```
<form>
    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="testDatabaseNewUser()">
</form>
```

My controller:

```
angular.module('appDatabaseCtrl', [])
.controller('databaseCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log',
    function($scope, $http, $log){
        $scope.testDatabaseNewUser = function(){
            $http.post('api/New_User').success(function(data) {
                $log.info("succes!");
                $log.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status){
                $log.error("error!");
                $log.log(data);
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

In my API, I have:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'config/config.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->post('/New_User', 'addUser');

$app->run();

function DB_Connection() {
    global $dbparams;
    $dbhost = $dbparams['host'];
    $dbuser = $dbparams['user'];
    $dbpass = $dbparams['password'];
    $dbname = $dbparams['dbname'];
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}

function addUser($req, $resp, $args) {
    ...
}

?>
```

Knowing all that, I just want to access the content of my form in my addUser function. I knew that I could pass those information's in the url, but I would like a way that doesn't need me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it's exactly like  Alvaro suggested but the code in the API is a bit different:

```
function addUser($req, $resp, $args) {
    $user = json_decode($req->getBody());
    $user->privilege;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the request method 'POST' you can pass some information in the BODY of the request.

In angular you can do like:

passing the object in `$http.post('api/New_User')` function

> $http.post('api/New_User',object)

**HTML**:

```
<form>
    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username"><br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="text" name="password" ng-model="user.password">
    <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="testDatabaseNewUser()">
</form>
```

**Your** **Controller**:

```
angular.module('appDatabaseCtrl', [])
.controller('databaseCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log',
    function($scope, $http, $log){
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.testDatabaseNewUser = function(){
            $http.post('api/New_User', $scope.user).success(function(data) {
                $log.info("succes!");
                $log.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status){
                $log.error("error!");
                $log.log(data);
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

In you **PHP**:

```
function addUser($req, $resp, $args) {
    ...
    $req.body ...
}
```

I guess this will help

> http://www.angularcode.com/demo-of-a-simple-crud-restful-php-service-used-with-angularjs-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was just like Alvaro said but a little bit different.

In PHP:

```
function addUser($req, $resp, $args) {
    $user = json_decode($req->getBody());

    //Than I can just use
    $user->username;
    $user->password;
}
```